# HTML meta viewport is cutting my layout. Why is it happening?

Tags: html, css

I am building a responsive web page. Now I am going to start working with media queries, but when I insert `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` and make the screen get smaller, part of the background of my header, first section and footer is cutted, remaining only a part of them and white space with their text. You can see it in the on the snippet. Why is it happening and what can I do do fix it?

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Doppio+One|Open+Sans&display=swap');
body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
}
header{
    background-color: rgb(93, 158, 76);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 30px;
}
header img{
    width: 45px;
}
header h1{
    font-family: 'Doppio One', cursive;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: rgb(214, 245, 210);
}
nav ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}
nav ul li a{
    margin-left: 55px;
}
nav a{
    color: rgb(230, 245, 229);
    font-size: 17px;
}
nav a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(143, 182, 135);
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin: 0 -15px 0 40px;
}
#firstsection{
    background-image: url(Images/coffee-3289259_1280.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 900px;
    position: relative;
}
#firstsection div{
    margin-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 150px;
    color: rgb(47, 119, 27);
    text-align: center;
}
#firstsection h1{
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}
#firstsection div a{
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid rgb(47, 119, 27);
    padding: 13px 30px;
    font-size: 16.5px;
    color: rgb(47, 119, 27);
}
#firstsection div a:hover{
    color: rgb(133, 163, 131);
    border: 2px solid rgb(133, 163, 131);
}
#textboxes{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#middlesection div div{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px 60px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(93, 158, 76);
    padding: 30px 30px;
}
#middlesection img:first-of-type{
    width: 55px;
}
#middlesection h2{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#lastsection{
    text-align: center;
}
#lastsection img{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 100px auto 0px;
}
#lastsection div{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 450px;
}
#lastsection div a:visited{
    color: blue;
}
footer{
    background-color: rgb(93, 158, 76);
    padding: 15px;
    color: rgb(214, 245, 210);
    font-size: 14px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
footer img{
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
footer div{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Finances | Manage your money easily</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta name="description" content="Control you spending and manage your money easily. Your finances by the short hairs.">
        <meta name="author" content="Bruno M. B. Sdoukos">
        <meta name="keywords" content="finances, managing money, spending control">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/icons8-fund-accounting-80.png"></a>
            <a href="index.html"><h1>Finances</h1></a>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <section id="firstsection">
                <div>
                    <h1>Manage your money easily, anywhere, anytime.</h1>
                    <a href="#">Get started</a>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section id="middlesection">
                <div id="textboxes">
                    <div>
                        <img src="Images/icons8-increase-64.png">
                        <h3>Concrete data</h3>
                        <p>Simple but concrete data that are the answer to all the quesions about your current money, spending and.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="Images/icons8-navigation-toolbar-left-filled-50 (1).png">
                        <h3>Easy interface</h3>
                        <p>An interface easy to use, made to you who want to manage your money faster and with no problems.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="Images/icons8-natural-user-interface-2-filled-50.png">
                        <h3>Fast access</h3>
                        <p>No complications that make you lose time. Just some clicks and done, you are in Finances, with all you need.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section id="lastsection">
                <img src="Images/board-1362851_1280.png">
                <div>
                    <h2>Register now and enjoy<br>the best of Finances.</h2>
                    <a href="#">Create an account</a>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <img src="Images/icons8-fund-accounting-80.png">
            <div>
                <p>A work of Bruno Sdoukos.</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You mean to say the header does not take the full width and there is a white space on the right?

Comment: Yes, but the text is appearing on the right. The background color is not appearing. The same happens with footer.

Comment: It is so because as you said the website isn't responsive. More precisely your header isn't responsive.

Comment: So what should I do to make the header and the footer span 100% of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have made some changes to your code. The initial problem was with the midsection. When the midsection has a width greater than the screen width a horizontal scrollbar appears to allow the user to see the rest of the content.
To fix that you could make the alignment vertical instead of horizontal depending on the width of the screen. In the solution below I wrap the content.

The second problem was when the width of the contents in the header exceeds the width of the screen that is when the width of the container tries to be the same width as the screen(remember the `meta name="viewport"`) but the content overflows(as it has a greater width).
To fix that you could show your header items inside of a menu. In my solution below I have just made it take no space in the header(`display: none`). E.g solution might be like [this](https://itnext.io/how-to-build-a-responsive-navbar-using-flexbox-and-javascript-eb0af24f19bf).

**NOTE:** The solution below does not have elegant styling maybe you could add a padding here and there to make it look elegant

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Finances | Manage your money easily</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Control you spending and manage your money easily. Your finances by the short hairs."
    />
    <meta name="author" content="Bruno M. B. Sdoukos" />
    <meta
      name="keywords"
      content="finances, managing money, spending control"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("topulid");
        if (x.className === "topul") {
          x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
          x.className = "topul";
        }
      }
    </script>
    <header>
      <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/icons8-fund-accounting-80.png"/></a>
      <a href="index.html"><h1>Finances</h1></a>
      <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main>
      <section id="firstsection">
        <div>
          <h1>Manage your money easily, anywhere, anytime.</h1>
          <a href="#">Get started</a>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="middlesection">
        <div id="textboxes">
          <div>
            <img src="Images/icons8-increase-64.png" />
            <h3>Concrete data</h3>
            <p>
              Simple but concrete data that are the answer to all the quesions
              about your current money, spending and.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <img
              src="Images/icons8-navigation-toolbar-left-filled-50 (1).png"
            />
            <h3>Easy interface</h3>
            <p>
              An interface easy to use, made to you who want to manage your
              money faster and with no problems.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="Images/icons8-natural-user-interface-2-filled-50.png" />
            <h3>Fast access</h3>
            <p>
              No complications that make you lose time. Just some clicks and
              done, you are in Finances, with all you need.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="lastsection">
        <img src="Images/board-1362851_1280.png" />
        <div>
          <h2>Register now and enjoy<br />the best of Finances.</h2>
          <a href="#">Create an account</a>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <img src="Images/icons8-fund-accounting-80.png" />
      <div>
        <p>A work of Bruno Sdoukos.</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Doppio+One|Open+Sans&display=swap");
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}
header {
  background-color: rgb(93, 158, 76);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
header img {
  width: 45px;
}
header h1 {
  font-family: "Doppio One", cursive;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: rgb(214, 245, 210);
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.topnav a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.icon {
  display: none;
}

#firstsection {
  background-image: url(Images/coffee-3289259_1280.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 900px;
  position: relative;
}
#firstsection div {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 150px;
  color: rgb(47, 119, 27);
  text-align: center;
}
#firstsection h1 {
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}
#firstsection div a {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid rgb(47, 119, 27);
  padding: 13px 30px;
  font-size: 16.5px;
  color: rgb(47, 119, 27);
}
#firstsection div a:hover {
  color: rgb(133, 163, 131);
  border: 2px solid rgb(133, 163, 131);
}
#textboxes {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  margin-top: 50px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#middlesection div div {
  text-align: center;
  /* margin: 15px 0px; */
  border: 2px solid rgb(93, 158, 76);
  padding: 30px 30px;
  max-width: 300px;
}
#middlesection img:first-of-type {
  width: 55px;
}
#middlesection h2 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
#lastsection {
  text-align: center;
}
#lastsection img {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 100px auto 0px;
}
#lastsection div {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 450px;
}
#lastsection div a:visited {
  color: blue;
}
footer {
  background-color: rgb(93, 158, 76);
  padding: 15px;
  color: rgb(214, 245, 210);
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
footer img {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
footer div {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
  .topnav a {
    display: none;
  }
  .icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple global reset with:

```
html, 
body,
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

then set the body to:

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
}
```